Question about a particular detail in triangle-freeness of graphs proof
In The Probabilistic Method by Alon and Spencer, after Szemeredi's Regularity Lemma is introduced, its application on triangle-free graphs is shown with a lemma. In one statement in the proof below, however, I have a question.
For context, the proof is attached at the end of this post.

Indeed, if $X_1$ is the set of all vertices of $V_1$ that have less than $\frac{1}{4}\epsilon c$ neighbors in $V_2$ then its cardinality must be smaller than $\frac{1}{4}\epsilon c$, since otherwise the pair $X_1$ and $X_2 = V_2$ together with the fact that $d(V_1, V_2) \ge \frac{1}{2}\epsilon$, would violate the $(\epsilon/4)$-regularity of this pair.

To prove the "indeed" condition, I used contradiction like the statement suggests. FTSOC, assume that the cardinality of $X_1$ is greater than $\frac{1}{4}\epsilon c$. In that case, the best we can say is $$d(X_1, V_2) = \frac{\text{edges between $X_1$ and $V_2$}}{|X_1| \cdot |V_2|}\le \frac{\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\epsilon c}_{\text{maximum possible # of neighbors of a } v \space \in \space X_1 } \cdot \underbrace{c}_{\text{maximum possible value of } |X_1|}}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\epsilon c}_{\text{minimum possible value of } |X_1|} \space \cdot \underbrace{c}_{|V_2|}} = 1$$
But this doesn't tell us anything, whereas the statement indicates that this should lead to a contradiction. To violate the regularity condition, we'd need to show that $d(X_1, V_2) \le \frac{1}{4}\epsilon c$, but I can't understand how to prove this and the best I can do is $\le 1$ which is useless anyway.


This is probably a really dumb question but please help me regardless, lol.

Somehow you did not find the best bound...
$$
d(X_1, V_2) = \frac{\text{edges between $X_1$ and $V_2$}}{|X_1| \cdot |V_2|}\le \frac{\sum_{x \in X_1} E(x, V_2)}{|X_1| |V_2|} < \frac{|X_1| \frac{1}{4} \epsilon c}{|X_1| |V_2|} \leq \frac{1}{4} \epsilon.
$$

Oh my god. I wrote $c$ instead of $|X_1|$ in the numerator because that would be the maximum possible cardinality of it. I had no idea it would cancel.
